Как установить гостевые дополнения Virtual Box на CentOS 9 stream?
Я очень много способов пробовал, система обновлена, ядра тоже. Но почему-то не хотят ставятся. У меня есть много виртуальных машин(Windows server 2019, Arch Linux, Debian, Kali Linux) и на всех работают гостевые дополнения, а тут нет.
Вот еще файл логов(/var/log/vboxadd-setup.log):



Пробовали-то сделать то, что здесь написано?

Прочитать логи?

Видимо это про это https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/22099

И там по ссылке пишут, что должно быть достаточно просто установить гостевые дополнения из пакетов, а не возиться с ручной сборкой

А virtualbox-guest-additions из EPEL не подтягивается?
